# Sudden drop in reputation for no apparent reason in SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

[users/165297/amarghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165297/amarghosh)

Yesterday night (Friday - I'm in India, so it is UTC + 5:30) I had a little above 4000 reputation points. Today morning I was surprised to find it to be 4200 something - apparently someone upvoted many of my top answers until I hit the rep cap (thanks dude). I even had a couple of non-rep-yielding up-votes and the total for the day showed 215. Then I [received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774846/how-to-search-replace-text-with-an-a-href-wrapper-in-javascript/1774855#1774855) three down-votes and two up-votes, and signed off somewhere around 4250.

But just now I logged in to find that my rep is back at 4075 and most of the yesterday's up-votes are not shown in the recent tab - it shows that total rep earned yesterday was 35, but still has a non-rep-yielding vote (vote count shows 1, but nothing on the rep portion). I figured that yesterday's sudden increase might have be a bug and it was fixed (or the  guy changed his mind and cancelled them) - but interestingly, my top-posts in the profile page haven't lost those votes. My top voted posts had 5 votes each before yesterday and it became six after the bulk up-votes. They still have six votes each after the drop in rep. So I have a feeling that it is a bug. Could someone look into this and tell me what happened?

**In short:** The post pages show that they do have 6 votes, but my reputation doesn't reflect them - it was somehow rolled back. And according to recent activity page, I hit the cap on Friday with 35 points (it shows a non-rep vote in there).

PS: Don't take it just as a cry for the lost 200 rep points - I'm curious to know what happened.

Comment: @Amarghosh - John's answer sounds about right; it is very rare, but not unheard of, that this causes a problem - somebody *thinking* they are showing massive gratitude actually messing up your rep. Since suspicious votes are *completely* removed it is impossible for me to see where they came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The daily script hunting for vote abuse has detected the voting pattern of your "friend". So it decided to undo all these upvotes. Afterwards a rep-recalc dropped your points to the amount you've seen today.

It could be the case that your answers where also upvoted from someone else, after hitting the cap. So maybe the posts with 6 upvotes are correct, maybe not. You can wait here for a moderator to look at it, or flag one of your posts, explaining your issue.

Comment: Thanks John. I'd wait for a moderator here.